# Как на денвере убрать алиас icons?

Tags: .htaccess, denwer, чпу, сервер

А то мне нужно сделать раздел icons на сайте, а он мне иконки Apache выводит.

Answer (score 1):

htaccess поправить для конкретной папки сайта.

Comment: и как править?